# How to show only present tense sentense in facebook stories?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I Have created a "want to go" action and created a story for it. But while posting on Facebook timeline statement is like 'shraddha wanted to go to..(past tense)' instead of 'shraddha wants to go to'. I want only present tense in statements of stories posted on Facebook timeline

Answer (score 0):

Facebook automatically adds the correct tense based on the time of the post and the time specified for the action, and that is correct for most of the applications.

You can "hack" the graph action by translating your action with present tense even when facebook ask you to use past tense.

To do this got to the developer page, edit the action and then under the Stories section click edit tense.

Hope this helps

Comment: No this is not working.. I had tried this too.